# How to programmatically send an event from a site on JavaScript to insert it on Google Calendar?

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

A user of my site(JavaScript)  often needs to create an event on his profile calendar (on my website) and send it also to his Google calendar, he does not log in with Google Accounts but he can give me authorization to get access to his calendar data to insert, remove, list and update events; so I can store an refresh token for when I need to access data (private, public).

Google documentation lets us create event as on this [Link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert); for calendarId, it suggest to use the "primary" keyword for the currently logged in user; also I can use the [calendarList.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) method to get an email of the user's calendar.

But even with this method. I don't find a way on how to use a user's refresh token to retrieve calendarId and insert his event on his calendar for the logged in user without Google Account.

Is it possible, using Google API, refresh token and access token to retrieve calendarId and insert an event?

Comment: JavaScript based site 

Answer (score 0):

If the user is using his Google Calendar to insert events, then it will [sync](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/151674?hl=en) to his account wherever he opens it. I suggest that you stick with using Gmail address tho to avoid these kind of hurdles.

Check the [Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) for the supported way of using Google calendar API. If it's not stated, it might not be supported.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,  I cheked it before , is not useful  in my case.  All I want is to be able to insert an event from website to his calendar using calebdar API.  Any help?